# What makes something iterable in python

Tags: python

What makes something iterable in Python? ie. can loop over it with `for`

Is it possible for me to create an iterable class in Python?  If so, how?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To make a class iterable, write an `__iter__()` method that returns an iterator:

```
class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [42, 3.1415, "Hello World!"]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.list)

m = MyList()
for x in m:
    print(x)
```

prints

```
42
3.1415
Hello World!
```

The example uses a list iterator, but you could also write your own iterator by either making `__iter__()` a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) or by returning an instance of an iterator class that defines a [`__next__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method.

Comment: There's also another way with `__getitem__`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/284795

Comment: @ColonelPanic is right, if you define `__getitem__` the class is also iterable. However it will ignore that you also defined `__len__` and just iterate indefinitely.

Answer (score 9):

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) describes exactly this:

> One method needs to be defined for container objects to provide iteration support:

```
container.__iter__()
```

> Return an iterator object. The object is required to support the iterator protocol described below. If a container supports different types of iteration, additional methods can be provided to specifically request iterators for those iteration types. (An example of an object supporting multiple forms of iteration would be a tree structure which supports both breadth-first and depth-first traversal.) This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.
>
> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the iterator protocol:

```
iterator.__iter__()
```

> Return the iterator object itself. This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the for and in statements. This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.

```
iterator.next()
```

> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception. This method corresponds to the tp_iternext slot of the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.

Answer (score 5):

Any object with an `__iter__()` method is considered an iterable.

Additionally, any sequence (objects that have an `__getitem__()` method) could return an iterator. An iterator is an object with a `__next__()` method that returns the next object in the sequence and throws a StopIteration exception.

Answer (score -2):

You'll want `next()` and `__iter__()` methods. [Here's a nice little tutorial](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmagwene/Bio313/master/lecture-13/PyIterGen.pdf).

Comment: That tutorial is only for Python 2. For the record, Python 3 existed when this answer was posted. Here is [one](http://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/) for Python 3.