# summing nested iterables with map-reduce/itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, mapreduce, python-itertools

I've been stuck with this data structure for a while now:

```
iter([iter([1,0]),iter([1,1]),iter([0,0])])
```

I want to get to sum of the inner-most elements using map-reduce/itertools.

I am able to get to the answer fairly quickly using for loops:

```
outer_iter = iter([iter([1,0]),iter([1,1]),iter([0,0])])

for inner_iter in outer_iter:
    for inner_list in inner_iter:
        total = total + inner_list
```

I am struggling to "translate" the code.

Comment: Can the iterables be nested *arbitrary* deep, or only two levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is nested *two levels* deep, We can use the `chain` function to concatenate the iterables together, and then let `sum(..)` calculate the sum of the iterable. So:

```
from itertools import chain

sum(chain.from_iterable(outer_iter))
```

`chain.from_iterable` takes as input an iterable of iterables, and converts this into an iterable that lazily obtains the elements from the iterables one at a time. We can use iterable unpacking on `chain`, but if the outer iterable is an infinite list, the algorithm would get stuck (and eventually run out of memory).

Comment: something I noticed when playing with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403401/python-for-loop-and-iterator-behavior

Comment: @lainglo: yes, the iterator is indeed consumed. But there is not really a way to not consume the iterator. You can use `tee` etc. that will produce two iterators out of one (by using shared memory)

Answer (score 0):

This is an iterator of iterator of int's.

1. Flatten to obtain just an iterator of int's
2. Sum this iterator

We can use [Pyterator](https://github.com/remykarem/pyterator) for this (disclaimer: I'm the author).

```py
from pyterator import iterate

iterate(outer_iter).flatten().sum()
```