# Mock object is not iterable

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am currently trying (and failing) to perform unit tests on my simple app which posts data to a MySQL database. Below is the unit test I am trying to run, not sure if this will eve test my code successfully, but is coming up with a TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable

Unit_Test.py

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from unittest.mock import Mock


from source.src.scores import *


@mock.patch('source.src.scores.request')
def test_add_scores(self):
    columns = ["Match_ID", "Home_Score", "Away_Score"]
    values = [1, 1, 1]

    expected_score = {columns[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(columns))}

    with patch('source.src.scores.mysql.connector') as patch_connector:

        cursor = Mock()
        cursor.fetchone.return_value = values
        cursor.column_names = columns
        connect = Mock()
        connect.cursor.return_value = cursor

        patch_connector.connect.return_value = connect

        with patch('source.src.scores.jsonify') as json:
            json.return_value = expected_score

            json_return, http_code = add_score()

        assert patch_connector.connect.called
        assert connect.cursor.called
        assert connect.commit.called
        assert cursor.fetchone.called
        self.assertEqual(cursor.execute.call_count, 2)
        self.assertDictEqual(expected_score, json_return)


if __name__ == '__main__':
test_add_scores()
```

scores.py

```
 def execute_query(cursor, qry):
print("Executing query...")
cursor.execute(qry)


def execute_query_json(cursor, qry, cnx):
print("Executing JSON query...")
cursor.execute(qry, (request.json['Match_ID'],
                     request.json['Home_Score'],
                     request.json['Away_Score'],
                     )
               )
cnx.commit()


def add_score():
cnx = conn_db()
cursor = cnx.cursor()
print("Updating score")

execute_query_json(cursor, "INSERT INTO scores (Match_ID, Home_Score, Away_Score) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", cnx)
execute_query(cursor, "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE Score_ID=" + str(cursor.lastrowid))
recs = extract_records(cursor)

return jsonify({'discipline':recs}), 201
```

Any helps is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to specify which line the error occurs at. In the case of the "not iterable" error usually its just because we used [] where we should use () or something.

Comment: can you post the stack trace, please.

Comment: Unrelated, but prefer `{k:v for k, v in zip(columns, values)}` (or even `dict(zip(columns, vertices))` to iterating over indices.

Answer (score 10):

When you create a mock, you sometimes have to let it know how to respond to some of the calls that will be expected of it.  Take, for example:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []
```

If you were to create a Mock to use in place of an instance of `A`, the mock wouldn't automagically know how to respond if you attempt to request `.items`.  You can overcome this by telling the Mock what to return for a particular property by passing that as a keyword to the constructor, like so:

```
mocked_a = Mock(items = [])
```

Now, when you call `mock_a.items` you'll get an empty list, so iteration won't fault.

Answer (score 4):

To make mock iterable you need to mock its `__iter__` method. For example:

```py
cursor = Mock()
cursor.__iter__.return_value = []
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable` is telling you one of your mocked object is not iterable: you are trying but cannot iterate through it (`for elem in ...`) or call `list()` on it. For an object to be iterable it needs to implement the `__iter__` 'magic' method (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262255/12519542)

The `MagicMock` object (which you import in your test) [implements `__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magicmock-and-magic-method-support) along with other double-underscore magic methods. You could try making your `cursor` and `connect` object `MagicMock` instances instead.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while, trying different things. The MagicMock() never works for me, but the Magic() does.  Thanks!

This works:

mocked_a = Mock(items = [])

Then, mocked_a.items will return []

This with Mock() doesn't work, neither with MagicMock().  I can't assign [] to cursor, regardless of how I tried!

```
cursor = Mock()

cursor.__iter__.return_value = []

or:

cursor = MagicMock()

cursor.__iter__.return_value = []
```