# Problem with iteration in linked list structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, iterator

I have a problem with my `__iter__()` implementation for a Linked List structure. I wanted to implement it without using `yield` and `iter()`.

With one loop it works fine, but when I add a nested loop, the outer loop only iterates once and exits after the inner loop has finished:

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data, next=None):
            self.data, self.next = data, next

    def __init__(self, seq=None):
        self.head = self.tail = None
        self.extend(seq)
        self.current = self.head

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.current:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            temp = self.current.data
            self.current = self.current.next
            return iter(self.current)

    def extend(self, seq):
        for val in reversed(seq):
            node = self.Node(val, self.head)
            if self.tail is None:
                self.tail = node
            self.head = node

ll = LinkedList(range(10, 101, 10))
for val in ll:
    for val2 in ll:
        print((val, val2))
```

This produces the wrong output:

> (10, 20) (10, 30) (10, 40) (10, 50) (10, 60) (10, 70) (10, 80) (10, 90) (10, 100)

While I expect to also get tuples where the first value is 20, 30, ...etc.

Comment: The linked list should return a separate iterator object (of its own class) on `__iter__()`. It must also return a new, independent object on each call. This object (its class) must implement `__next__`.

Comment: [what-makes-something-iterable-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262235/what-makes-something-iterable-in-python)

Comment: @PatrickArtner sorry, its edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with a nested loop like this:

```
ll = LinkedList([1,2,3,4])
for val in ll:
    for val2 in ll:
        print((val, val2))
```

...is that for the nested loop, you'll have the same iterator instance, which is the linked list itself, which has just one `current` property. So when the inner loop has finished, that `current` will be `None`, and the outer loop will then call `__next__` only to find that `current` is `None`. So it exits.

You need to move away from `return self` in the `__iter__` function. Instead you should return something unique *every* time `__iter__` is called.

So define a class specifically for that purpose.

NB: there is also an error in the last line of your `__next__` implementation: it should return `temp`.

```
class LinkedList:
    class Iterator:
        def __init__(self, current):
            self.current = current

        def __next__(self):
            if not self.current:
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                temp = self.current.data
                self.current = self.current.next
                return temp  # <-- correction

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data, next=None):
            self.data, self.next = data, next

    def __init__(self, seq=None):
        self.head = self.tail = None
        self.extend(seq)
        self.current = self.head

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.Iterator(self.head)  # <--- new instance!

    def extend(self, seq):
        for val in reversed(seq):
            self.head = self.Node(val, self.head)
            if self.tail is None:
                self.tail = self.head

# now the nested iteration works...
ll = LinkedList([1,2,3,4])
for val in ll:
    for val2 in ll:
        print((val, val2))
```